# Stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset behaving weirdly on circle in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, cross-browser, stroke-dasharray

I'm using a `<circle>` element with `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to draw an indicator for the focused element of a donut chart, and in Safari it is not coming out right.

The outer pies are `<path>`s which work fine in all browsers, but as I need the indicator to transition between sectors they need to be `<circle>`s.

I thought it was because Safari was calculating the circle's circumference based on the svg viewbox or something like that but no dice. Any help would be appreciated.

https://codepen.io/pouretrebelle/pen/d56df310e385a0c2fdedb5bbddc2308d

Rendered in Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Rendered in Safari:
[image: Safari]

Comment: I've tested it with `viewBox="-100 -100 200 200"` and had no problems. Maybe Safari have a hard time with very small numbers